# "Specified type is not registered" error when bulk inserting table with geospatial data types

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the `SqlBulkCopy` class from the `System.Data` assembly (4.6.1) to bulk insert a table with a geospatial data type, using code that looks roughly like this (adapted from https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities):

```
public void InsertItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string schema, string tableName, IList<ColumnMapping> properties, DbConnection storeConnection, int? batchSize)
{
    using (var reader = new EFDataReader<T>(items, properties))
    {
        var con = (SqlConnection)storeConnection;
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            copy.BatchSize = batchSize ?? 15000; //default batch size
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(schema))
            {
                copy.DestinationTableName = $"[{schema}].[{tableName}]";
            }
            else
            {
                copy.DestinationTableName = "[" + tableName + "]";
            }

            copy.NotifyAfter = 0;

            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount))
            {
                copy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, properties[i].NameInDatabase);
            }
            copy.WriteToServer(reader); // <-- throws here
            copy.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

That works great, until I try to use it on a table with geospatial data. When I do that, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Swyfft.Console.TaskManager - Error running task SeedRating: 
(InvalidOperationException) The given value of type DbGeography from the data source cannot be converted to type udt of the specified target column.;   
(ArgumentException) Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.;
   at Swyfft.Data.Utilities.SqlQueryProvider.InsertItems[T](IEnumerable`1 items, String schema, String tableName, IList`1 properties, DbConnection storeConnection, Nullable`1 batchSize) in C:\source\swyfft\swyf-website\Swyfft.Data.Utilities\SqlQueryProvider.cs:line 78
   at Swyfft.Data.Utilities.EFBatchOperation`2.InsertAll[TEntity](IEnumerable`1 items, DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 batchSize) in C:\source\swyfft\swyf-website\Swyfft.Data.Utilities\EFBatchOperation.cs:line 138
   at Swyfft.Data.Rating.RatingContext.BulkInsert[T](IEnumerable`1 entities, Nullable`1 batchSize) in C:\source\swyfft\swyf-website\Swyfft.Data.Rating\RatingContext.cs:line 69
   at Swyfft.Seeding.CsvLoaders.CsvLoader.ProcessCsv[T](StreamReader streamReader, String fileName, ISwyfftContext ctx, Func`2 parserFunc) in C:\source\swyfft\swyf-website\Swyfft.Seeding\CsvLoaders\CsvLoader.cs:line 133
   at Swyfft.Seeding.CsvLoaders.CsvLoader.InitializeCountyBlockQualities(String stateFilter) in C:\source\swyfft\swyf-website\Swyfft.Seeding\CsvLoaders\InitializeCountyBlockQualities.cs:line 35
```

I've Googled around, to not much avail. I've traced down the call chain, deep into the bowels of the SqlBulkCopy assembly (thanks, Resharper!), but the error seems to be hidden down deeper than I've been able to dig. I've tried installing (and loading) the appropriate SQL Server Types package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/), but no dice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: using my phone was a bad idea. I solved my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I got it fixed. The problematic code was in the `EFDataReader<T>` class (that I'd borrowed from https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities/blob/master/EntityFramework.Utilities/EntityFramework.Utilities/EFDataReader.cs). Its `GetValue(int ordinal)` originally looked like this:

```
public override object GetValue(int ordinal)
{
    return Accessors[ordinal](Enumerator.Current);
}
```

But that meant that it was returning any db-agnostic `DbGeometry` and `DbGeography` values that happened to come through *as* `DbGeometry` and `DbGeography`, which the SqlBulkCopy class didn't understand. They actually need to be SQL-Server specific, i.e., `SqlGeography` and `SqlGeometry`, like so:

```
public override object GetValue(int ordinal)
{
    object value = Accessors[ordinal](Enumerator.Current);

    var dbgeo = value as DbGeography;
    if (dbgeo != null)
    {
        var chars = new SqlChars(dbgeo.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText);
        return SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(chars, dbgeo.CoordinateSystemId);
    }

    var dbgeom = value as DbGeometry;
    if (dbgeom != null)
    {
        var chars = new SqlChars(dbgeom.WellKnownValue.WellKnownText);
        return SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(chars, dbgeom.CoordinateSystemId);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with command.parameter.add  `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@deviceGeolocation", SqlDbType.Udt) { UdtTypeName = "Geography", Value = geo, });`                                                            
Below is the exception   `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Specified type is not registered on the target server.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91.`

Answer (score 0):

> **FORWARD:** I realize my expertise is not in `C#` *yet*, so I can only draw from my own `ETL` experiences that is similar to your error.
>   Likely, the problem may come down to your assumptions about the
>   well-formed nature of the data and how this is being fed into `SQL`.

A trip to [Spatial Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx) from MSDN informs us that the data needs to be well-formed....we knew that already...but have we assumed so on the source data?

You are using `CSVLoader`, which comes from an external source, and in my own experience using `SSIS`, data is *not always structured correctly* in the file. As mentioned, `SQL Server` will balk at ill-formed `spatial data types` that violate the columns datatype constraints.

- Have you qualified your data before using the call method?
- Are you using `spatial datatypes` that are `instantiable`?
- Have you tried splitting the Bulk data up to test the consistency throughout the file(s) that `CSVLoader` retrieves them? Perhaps only part of your data is corrupt.

Since this is an integration operation, have you considered setting up a staging table to handle cleansing/transformation of your presumed well-formed data?

`CSV` files are simple text files, so there is an implicit/explicit conversion between the `CSVLoader` and when `SQL Server` attempts to insert the rows by batch into the database. `SQL Server` cannot violate the `ACID` elements.

I cannot stress enough not to assume facts from your data and how `C#`, let alone `SQL Server`, reads and converts them. I have spent many an hour struggling with simple `CSV` files in `SSIS` before realizing that my `IS` was parsing the file in a way that was unable to handle inconsistencies in the `CSV` file (some of the data was corrupt or missing).

Hopefully, this will help you on your way to solving the problem.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In this case, I happen to know that the file is formed correctly - it was loading correctly previously, using the EntityFramework.BulkInsert library - see https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/. Unfortunately, that library has a bug in it that doesn't allow it to parse multicolumn foreign keys, and it stopped working when we added one. So I'm trying to find an alternative.

Comment: @Ken.Smith Perhaps using the ETL strategy might be called for? Your goal is getting it into SQL server in a way that does not lose information, right? Can you safely convert any datatypes into your spatial datatypes? You can always fix the problem, just not have to lose use of the data today.