# "Specified type is not registered on the target server.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography" Exception while working with SQLGeography data type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core, sqlgeography

When trying to use SqlGeograpy I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Specified type is not registered on the target server.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91.
```

I am facing the above exception while adding SQLGeography type as command.parameter
even if I can see that I have that library in my SQL Server assemblies (select * from sys.assemblies)

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@deviceGeolocation", SqlDbType.Udt) { UdtTypeName = "Geography", Value = geo, });
```

Comment: Some of the answers [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Specified+type+is+not+registered+on+the+target+server.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography) look promising

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Specified type is not registered" error when bulk inserting table with geospatial data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407683/specified-type-is-not-registered-error-when-bulk-inserting-table-with-geospati)

Comment: Unforunatonly Stackoverrflow 'Bulk copy'(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407683/specified-type-is-not-registered-error-when-bulk-inserting-table-with-geospati) solution didn't work !!